# Android Studio or IntellIj export setting does not contain plugins list?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, android-studio-plugin

I always take backup of android studio settings by go `file > Export settings` then i get a `settings.jar` file.

Today i needed to reinstall Android Studio after a critical error. I needed old setting because old studio was not available, i used my previously exported `settings.jar`. I was shocked to see my bad that i did not get any of my plugins in new Android Studio after importing `settings.jar`.

Then i installed almost 25 of plugins again manually by searching and reminding. **:/**

My question is how can i backup my Android Studio plugins for future use?

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-172532. You can try https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html instead.

Comment: Is that mean, settings does not contain plugins? and i should share my IDE setting by sharing.

Comment: Yes, you can also copy the [plugins folder](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) manually.

Comment: In my case i need only C:\Users\raj\.AndroidStudio3.1\config\plugins Right, do i need to copy parent folder?